# how to send my list data at a particular index to another list's particular index in flutter

Tags: list, flutter

suppose my list 1 data is like this

```
[
    {
      key1: value1,
      key2: value2,
      key3: value3,
    },
    {
      key1: value4,
      key2: value5,
      key3: value6,
    },

    .....
]
```

what if i want to send

```
{
      key1: value4,
      key2: value5,
      key3: value6,
    },
```

to updatedList at index 1

my code is:

```
updatedList[0]= List.from(widget.allDataList[1]);
```

Comment: Do You want only index 1 value from list 1 ?

Comment: actually i want to pass 1 by 1 into another list

Comment: what would be the sequence? Could you please bit elaborate. what you want to achieve

Comment: if you see above i have 2 maps in my list i just want to pass my map 1 which is on index 1 to another list' first index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 void main() {
 var list = [];
  
  list =
   [
    {
      "key1": "value1",
      "key2": "value2",
      "key3": "value3",
    },
    {
      "key1": "value4",
      "key2": "value5",
      "key3": "value6",
    },
  ];
  
    
  List<Map<String, String>> updatedList=[];

  updatedList.insert(0, list[0]);
  
  print(updatedList);
}
```